# How does node.js achieve promise-awareness with local variables inside a for-loop?

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I have a `for-loop` which contains some local variables `n` that is declared inside the loop. So I expected the value of `n` to be destroyed once the program goes out of the loop.

However, it appears that the value of `n` is still available outside of the for-loop. Why is that? Also, when should I expect the value of `n (also the value k if uncommented)` to be destroyed?

```
const delayHelper = require('./delayExecutor')

async function main() {
  let promises = [];
  let records = [1, 2, 3, 4];

  for(let i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
    let n = 1000 + records[i];
    // let k = 123;
    promises.push(delayHelper.delayResolve(() => records[i], 1000).then(data => data + n))
  }

  console.log(await Promise.all(promises));   //print: [ 1002, 1004, 1006, 1008 ]
}

main()
```

```
//delayExecutor.js

let delayedResolve = (fun, ms) => {
  return new Promise((y, n) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      y(fun());
    }, ms);
  });
};

exports.delayResolve = delayedResolve;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of concepts to be noted here. 1. **Closure scope**, 2. **Block Scope**

when ever you are accessing `n` in the inner function definitions, the variable is kept alive in closure scope for that inner function until it is no longer needed,

The **usage of `let` to declare `n` will create a new variable in the block scope(`for` loop here)** which will be locked to the inner function in that corresponding iteration.

One more thing you can experiment is use `var` to declare `n` which will yield a different result - `[1005,1006,1007,1008]`. This is because `var` is not a block scoped declaration hence it will not create a new variable for each iteration of the loop. The final value of `n` by the time the loop ends is `1004` and that will be used in your logic `data => data + n`

and for the second part of your question - As far as I know, all the variable references will be cleared at the end of the function. Since your n is locked in the Closure scope of the inner function `data => data = n` the `n` value will be cleared once that gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

How did you find that `n` is accessible from outside of the loo? I executed you code and tried to access `n` outsize of the loop. I get **n is undefined** error. Which is totally expected.

Now, the garbage collector decides when the unused memory needed to be garbage collected. You can search for **V8 garbage collector**.

Comment: I'm thinking that because the `console.log` is able to access the value of `n` and prints [1002, 1004, 1006, 1008]. My expectation is that the value of `n` should somehow be put inside the `promises` array to be available in the `.then` block

Comment: You mean, why the value of `n` is accessible from `.then`? Because, `n` will behave like global to all the nested scope inside for loop! You are calling the `delayHelper.delayResolve` from inside the for loop's scope.

Answer (score -1):

With `Promise.all` promises will  process parallel and results will resolve (or reject)

```js
let delayedResolve = (fun, ms) => {
  return new Promise((y, n) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      y(fun());
    }, ms);
  });
};


Promise.all([1, 2, 3, 4].map(async item=>await delayedResolve(()=> item, 1000)+1000+item))
.then(results=>console.log(results));
```

The code will first process for each promise and then appear all results.
If you looks for sequential process, you need promise chaining.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question is that I don't understand why my code works

Comment: @Andyk. read about JS closure.